# Identify all select options within a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm adding **select** tags dynamically to a table as follows:

```
selectedRow = '<tr class="trResource">';
selectedRow += '<td align="center" width="15%"><select><option value="Primary Auditor">Primary Auditor</option><option value="Secondary Auditor">Secondary Auditor</option><option value="Auditee">Auditee</option></select></td>';
selectedRow += '</tr>';
$("#tblSeelctedProjectResource tr:first").after(selectedRow);
```

I need to check, whether the user has selected all the options. (i.e. Before I submit, 3 rows should available with all values selected) as follows:
(I need to check 1 Primary Auditor, 1 secondary Auditor and 1 Audtiee to be selected before i submit)

```
+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|    Username +   Required   | Level                                    |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|   User 1    |    YES       | Dropdown (Primary Auditor Selected)      |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|   User 2    |    YES       | Dropdown (Secondary Auditor Selected)    |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
|   User 3    |    YES       | Dropdown (Auditee  Selected)             |
+-------------+--------------+------------------------------------------+
```

I tried the following:

```
var _pa = $('#tblSeelctedProjectResource').find('select option:selected').text() == "Primary Auditor";
var _sa = $('#tblSeelctedProjectResource').find('select option:selected').text() == "Secondary Auditor";
var _ad = $('#tblSeelctedProjectResource').find('select option:selected').text() == "Auditee";
if (!_pa && !_sa && !_ad) {
return false;
}
return true;
```

Not Working, Please help me on this.

Comment: how can you select all option within single select list?.. rather put it as checkboxes and select them all or make multiselect list box.

Comment: please provide rendered html or a demo fiddle

Comment: You are checking whether any option in that select element has been selected or not.. Right..? By default the first option would get selected.. so you dont need to check this..

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I need to check 1 Primary Auditor, 1 secondary Auditor and 1 Audtiee to be selected before i submit

Comment: In that case you need to use `.each()` to get the values to all `select` elements and then compare using `val()` and not `text()`

Comment: @ShaunakD Are you having more than one select elements..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I guess OP wants those three options to be selected, in all three select boxes. It seems unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, collect all selected values from the drop downs:

```
var values = $('#tblSeelctedProjectResource select').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Then check whether those three options were selected (in any order):

```
return $.inArray("Primary Auditor", values) && 
    $.inArray("Secondary Auditor", values) &&
    $.inArray("Auditee", values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well the question, you create a select within n-rows, and you need to check if first has "Primary Auditor" value selected, and so on.
So you need to iterate all selects and query it's position and it's value, try this code

```
var check = true
$('#tblSeelctedProjectResource').find('select').each(function (i,obj){
    if ($(obj).text().trim() == "Primary Auditor"){
        check &= true
    }else if ($(obj).text().trim() == "Secondary Auditor"){
        check &= true
    }else if ($(obj).text().trim() == "Auditee"){
        check &= true
    }else{
        check = false
    }
});
return check
```

Comment: Nice one, But what if they select in different order? say (Secondary, Primary and Auditee) instead of regular order (Primary, Secondary and Auditee)

Comment: if all values must be present and order is not relevant, remove the position validation (i == x), see the last edit